# Jenkins Multi Branch Pipeline error with Jenkins file

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have create a Jenkins Multi Branch pipeline where I have used below script to trigger a declarative steps from Github an Jenkins version 2.222.3 .

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage ('Compile Stage') {

            steps {
                withMaven(maven : 'maven_3_5_0') {
                    sh 'mvn clean compile'
                }
            }
        }

        stage ('Testing Stage') {

            steps {
                withMaven(maven : 'maven_3_5_0') {
                    sh 'mvn test'
                }
            }
        }


        stage ('Deployment Stage') {
            steps {
                withMaven(maven : 'maven_3_5_0') {
                    sh 'mvn deploy'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have read  all the available docs on Jenkins but I am always landing on this weird error

[image: use of pipeline or node still continues to be error]

[image: use of pipeline or node still continues to be error]

I am not printing Start of pipeline which is highlighted in red in the above picture but it is pulling from somewhere.

Kindly request your kind assistance on fixing it as I am not aware of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a plugin and that's why it doesn't know what the `pipeline` means.

The [docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#_footnotedef_2) recommend https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-aggregator/.

Comment: Hi theonlyrao, I am unable to decide what the plugin we need to install actually. Can you please help me with name also or a id which i can search to add to Jenkins

Comment: There are instructions on how to install a plugin here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/#from-the-web-ui. Search for the plugin `Pipeline` with id `workflow-aggregator` like it says in the link I provided.

Comment: ```

node{
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                echo "Hello World!"
            }
        }
    }
}

```

Now I am getting below error

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: any for class: groovy.lang.Binding